# What if block_given? returns false?

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code, and I want to write a test for it.
It is part of an open source project, so I wasn't the one who wrote it.
I know  that `|c| yield c if block_given?` will execute the block that is given (if it is), but if not `block_given?` will return `false`. What will happen in that case? Thank you for your time.

```
::CSV
 .open(path, 'rb', opts)
 .tap { |c| yield c if block_given? }
 .to_a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to check it :)

```
def block
  (1..10)                .tap {|x| puts "original: #{x.inspect}"}
    .select {|x| x%2==0} .tap {|x| yield x if block_given?}
end
block { |x| puts "evens: #{x.inspect}"}
block
```

First call returns:

```
=> original: 1..10
=> evens: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Second call returns:

```
=> original: 1..10
```

If there is no block given the yield won't be called, so the empty block is going to be passed to `#tap`.

Comment: You can omit the `&block` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted :)